# SAS: Apparent Symbolic reference not resolved with call symptux

Tags: macros, sas

I have a dataset as follows:

```
ID Value
A 77
B 60
C 20
D 40
E 60
F 100
```

and I have another dataset with 6 variables, lets say

A1 - A6

I want to multiply the above values to A1-A6

like A1*value of A A2*value of B

so I created this way

```
data _null_ ; 
set have; 

call symputx('value' || trim(left(_n_)),value); 
call symputx('rows', _n_);
```

run;

and

```
data want; 
set have; 

array XX(*) A1 - A6; 
    do i=1 to &rows; 
        XX(i)=mgpc(i)* &&value&i ;
    end;
run;
```

However When I run this it says

```
Apparent symbolic reference i not allowed. 
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference VALUE not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference I not resolved.
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following:
          a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant,
          a datetime constant, a missing value, INPUT,
          PUT.
```

Comment: Is your array statement in the same step as your call symput?

Comment: No, both are in a seperate data steps

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of the code that causes this error message.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
data want; 
set have; 
array XX(*) A1 - A6; 
    do i=1 to &rows; 
        value=symget(cats('value',i));
        XX(i)=mgpc(i)* value;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: This is an amazing function @Shenglin Chen, it works thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using macro variable if you want to reference data set variables?

So you have a dataset, let's call it REFERENCE_TABLE, with the variable VALUE and you want to multiple some number in your current dataset by the I'th record from that reference dataset.  Use the POINT= option on a SET statement.

Say you have a dataset MYDATE with an array of variables that start with the letter X and you want to find the sum of X(i)*REFERENCE_VALUE(i).

```
data want ;
  set mydata ;
  array x x: ;
  total=0
  do i=1 to min(dim(x),nobs);
    set reference_table point=i nobs=nobs ;
    total = sum(total,x(i)*value);
  end;
run;
```

You could also probably make it more efficient by using an `IF _N_= THEN DO;` block of code to load the values into an array or hash object.